# How to store the core data files in the Private folder

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, encrypted-core-data-sql

I have released the iOS app to the user through Adhoc distribution. The user has installed the app and they are able to view the files such as sqlite files, images stored in the documents directory. This can be accessed through third party applications such as iExplorer, iMazing.

**Questions:**

1.Is it possible to store the data in private directory and that can’t be accessed by other sources or software.

2.Is there any library to encrypt the core data  and that shouldn’t be read by other applications?

I have tried with **following solutions** but that doesn’t help the way.

1.I have used the Data Protection attributes - NSFileProtectionComplete and NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen. But still the data is readable even the device is locked.

2.I have tried the SQLCipher library to encrypt the data but it doesn’t support for core data framework.

Please advice and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Application Support directory to store your DB files securely. You can get the path for that folder like this:

```
let appSupportDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for:.applicationSupportDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).last
```

You need to create that directory in a do/catch the first time you use it though:

```
try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: appSupportDirURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

Now add your DB file name to that path:

```
let storeURL = appSupportDirURL.appendingPathComponent("MyDatabaseName")
```

And finally use that url when you call `addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)` on your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to create the DB on disk.

I don't know of any libraries that help you encrypt the entire Core Data DB, but I actually don't think you need to do that once your DB file is not accessible anymore - at least not for apps with regular security requirements.

Comment: Hi Dorian , Thanks for your reply. I have used the application directory to store the files. But the file is readable/View in 3rd party softwares such as iExplorer, iMazing. Can you please advise on other approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment at first. Which directory do you mean with "application directory"?

Comment: Yes. I have stored the file in application directory but still it's readable from other 3rd party softwares such as iExplorer, iMazing.

Comment: So do you mean the "Application Support" directory? If so, did you create it with the path provided by the system like in the code above? It should result in the path /Library/Application Support/ inside the container, which is not exposed to iMazing, I just checked it